# How to import JS library from node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Can you please explain the ideology of using import/require libraries from node_modules folder.

I just want to use `konva.js` in my simple project, using `node.js` as a back end with live-server extension configured.

If I import it right into HTML file like this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.0.0/konva.min.js"></script>
<script> /*using konva library here or *.js*/</script>
```

Everything works
As I understood, this URL imports whole `konva.min.js` right into my HTML file

If I copy `konva.js` file from `/node_modules` package into my `/src` folder

And use code like this in my HTML

```
    <script src="konva.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

I have access to konva library in script.js

In server-side scripts, invoked by node.js I used statement like this to access packages in node_modules

```
var liveserver = require("live-server");
```

P.S. Why doesn't import work here? Node.js doesn't have import instructions?

But the main question is how to use the same syntax of require()/ import on client-side scripts and not to use `<script>` tags to import libraries?

```
 import konva from 'konva';
 /* js code next*/
```

OR

```
 var konva = require('konva');
 /* js code next*/
```

I need to use task managers? What should I do? Search for dependencies in each `.js` file and use tasks to import these dependencies right into project folder? But, for example, for gulp I found different libraries to format code, but can't find needed one to import dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js is a server-side runtime environment, what you need is to use the node_modules libraries on the client/browser side.

[**Using browserify**](https://github.com/browserify/browserify)

> browserify will recursively analyze all the require() calls in your
>   app in order to build a bundle you can serve up to the browser in a
>   single script tag.

It will bundle you require and import into a single js file for use in a script tag.

**Using import on client side**

```
<script type="module">
  import {addTextToBody} from './utils.mjs';

  addTextToBody('Modules are pretty cool.');
</script>
```

All you need is type=module on the script element, and the browser will treat the inline or external script as an ECMAScript module

```
// utils.mjs
export function addTextToBody(text) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

These are some great articles to get a better understanding of this :

- [ECMAScript modules in browsers](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)
- [ES6 Modules in depth](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-modules-in-depth)